# multiple buttons in one line of code in tkinter

Tags: python, button, tkinter

I need to create 200 check buttons in Tkinter, as I'm creating a seat selection screen. Is there a way of creating all of these buttons without having to type them out line by line, like you can in pygame? so far I've tried this but it doesn't seem to work. (I am not a super smart coder so it may be a silly mistake).

````
root = tk.Tk()

frame1 = tk.Frame(root)
frame1.pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.X)
button = list()
for i in range(4):
button.append(tk.Button(frame1, image=karirano, command=partial(klik, i)))
    button[-1].grid(row=0,column=i)
root.mainloop()```
````

Comment: what you mean `"like in pygame"` ? It would also need some loop to create buttons.

Comment: Why do you think the above doesn't work? What is it doing that is different than what you expect (other than crashing, because you haven't defined `klik`)? It's certainly possible to create widgets in loops. There's nothing particularly special about tkinter widgets -- they are just python classes.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can create buttons in a loop. If I were doing a seating chart, I would start by defining what it looks like with a simple data structure that lets you easily visualize the layout.

For example:

```
rows = {
    "a": "  xxxx xxxxxxxx xxxx",
    "b": "xxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxx",
    "c": "xxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxx",
}
```

You can then iterate over this data, placing a seat everywhere there is an "x".

For example:

```
for row_number, row_letter in enumerate(rows.keys()):
    for seat_number, c in enumerate(rows[row_letter]):
        if c == "x":
            seat = tk.Button(frame1, ...)
            seat.grid(row=row_number, column=seat_number)
```

Answer (score -1):

it appears it was just a syntax error, the code works how I wanted it to now.

Comment: despite you have solved the issue, you should also post the code in your answer. So I suggest including the code in your answer with an edit before you start getting downvotes.

Comment: The code in the question works as it was a syntax error earlier in my code